# C++ editor of choice for Java people?

Tags: java, c++, editor

We are a group of students trying to start up a C++ project. We have the most experience in Java because that is what were taught and I personally have experience in C, so this is going to be a learning experience for all of us. I am wondering which editing tool would be a good choice.

We also have access to all of the products of MSDNAA, so products like Microsoft Visual Studio is a potential option, however we plan to continue our project after we graduate, so our free license will expire at that time.

I understand that there are many, many free editors out there, but it is difficult to start looking without much direction.

Comment: If you're not planning for C#, have a look at eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tools). Maybe you're already familar with eclipse, so it may be a natural fit.

Comment: Or, if you are using Netbeans for your Java development, Netbeans (http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)

Comment: Voted down without any comment, on Aura's first question?  That's not very helpful. I swear I think the bar for downvotes is too low.  Aura, sorry that you got voted down without an explanation.  I think the reason for the downvotes is that this question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ . Stack Overflow is for actual programming questions.  Good luck on your project!

Comment: There is much more than the choice of a text editor. First chose a compiler, then chose an editor. You also didn't tell us what OS you're under.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you answers. I will definitely look into the editors that were mentioned. I will also keep in mind to ask programming related questions in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you never know until you try them all and pick whatever you like the most. Here are some IDEs for C++ that you can pick from (in the order of my preference):

- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)
- [vim](http://www.vim.org/)
- [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

One particularly good IDE, but works on Mac only, is [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).

Here are some Java IDEs that support C++:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)
- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

My personal opinion is that every IDE except Emacs, vim and QtCreator is not worth using. Eclipse becomes popular, but I don't feel like I need a slow as hell "combine-harvester" to write C++ code. Same goes for NetBeans. Others... well, try them and see.

Just remember that most IDEs support different build systems, so there is nothing wrong if everyone is using their IDE of choice while working on the same project. One of the good tools is [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), it can basically generate project files for many IDEs.

Comment: +1: I would suggest NetBeans has the best C++ integration, even though my favourite Java IDE is IntelliJ.

Comment: IntelliJ is the best Java IDE ever :-)

Answer (score 4):

Look no further than Eclipse. Traditionally geared towards Java, but I believe it also handles C++ these days.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: agreed. coming from a background of Java, Eclipse was the ideal transition.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already accustomed to Java programming, why not stick with Eclipse and/or Netbeans (not sure which you used)?

I personally prefer Visual Studio or Code::Blocks over those two for C++, but why not stay with what you know?

**IDEs**

[Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

[NetBeans C/C++](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)

[Visual Studio 2010 Professional](https://www.dreamspark.com/Products/Product.aspx?ProductId=25) (free for students as you mentioned)

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)